# cannot see syntax error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to build a binary search tree library and I'm getting a syntax error on my piece of code:

```
class Node:
    """
    Tree node: Left and Right child + data which can be any object
    """
    def __init__(self,data):
        """
        Node constructor
        """
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = data

def insert(self,data):                     # self --> object self.data
    """
    Insert new node with data
    """
    if data < self.data:                   # insert data less than current root 
        if self.left is None:              # if left node is empty, 
            self.left = Node(data)         # object left --> Node with new data
        else:
            self.left.insert(data)         # if left node is not empty, go insert again
    else:
        if self.right is None:             # insert data greater than current node
            self.right = Node(data)        # object right --> Node with new data
        else:
            self.right.insert(data)        # if not empty, run insert again


def lookup(self, data, parent = None):
    """
    Lookup node containing data
    """
    if data < self.data:
        if self.left is None:
            return None, None
        return self.left.lookup(data,self)   
    elif data > self.data:
        if self.right is None:
            return None, None
        return self.right.lookup(data,self)
    else:
        return self, parent

def delete(self, data):
    """
    delete node containing data
    """

    """ no child """
    if children_count == 0:
        # if node has no children, remove it
        if parent.left is node:        # if parent is pointing to current node
            parent.left = None         # set parent pointing left to None
        else:
            parent.right = None        # else set parent pointing right to None
        del node                       # del node

    """ 1 child """    
    elif children_count == 1:
        # if node has 1 child
        # replace node by it's child
        if node.left:
            n = node.left
        else:
            n = node.right
        if parent:
            if parent.left is node:
                parent.left = n
            else:
                parent.right = n
        del node

    """ 2 children """
    else:
        # if node has 2 children
        # find its successor 
        parent = node                                        # parent is equal to current node target of deletion
        successor = node.right                               # successor is right of the node
        while successor.left:                                 
            parent = successor                               
            successor = successor.left
        # replace node data by its successor data
        node.data = successor.data
        #fix successor's parent's child
        if parent.left == successor:
            parent.left = successor.right
        else:
            parent.right = successor.right


def children_count(self):
    """ Return the number of children """
    if node is None:
        return None
    cnt = 0
    if self.left:
        cnt += 1
    if self.right:
        cnt += 1
    return cnt


# method to print tree in order. Use recursion inside print_tree() to walk the tree breath-first 

def print_tree(self):
    if self.left:
        self.left.print_tree()
    print self.data,
    if self.right:
        self.right.print_tree()
```

the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    import BSTlib
  File "BSTlib.py", line 78
    elif children_count == 1:
       ^
```

I can't seem to see what is wrong =[ Can someone help me point this out? Thank you!

Comment: Can you add a few lines at the top of the code, above the line where your error occurs?

Comment: You'll need to share the code **leading up to** line 78. Try breaking this down to a [Short Self Contained Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) (and you may find you'll solve it yourself in the process).

Comment: Without more lines at the top it is impossible to say, but it looks like you probably have an unclosed parentheses on the line above the elif. That usually causes this kind of error because python only reaches an error when it tries to parse the next line as if it is still part of the same expression and gets an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an error with the docstring and whitespace. Run this code:

```
if False:
    print 'hi'

"""1 child"""
elif True:
    print 'sdf'
```

And you get a similar SyntaxError.

Remove the docstring (or just move it) and remove the extra whitespace:

```
if False:
    print 'hi'
elif True:
    print 'sdf'
```

---

If you need to comment, then just use the hash `#`:

```
if False:
    print 'hi'
# 1 child
elif True:
    print 'sdf'
```

Comment: Thank you for your input but that isn't it sorry

Comment: Thank you!! I understand! You saved me lots of time trying to figure this out because I thought my code looked fine to me